# Space of matrices having trace zero

Tags: general-topology

I know the definition of connected space. A connected space is in which there is no components. A space X is said to be disconnected if there exists two disjoint non empty open sets U and V such that $U \cup V = X$ . So, I want to know the set of matrices having trace zero is connected or disconnected? According to me this space is disconnected because it has three components one in which determinant is negative second which has det positive third which has det zero.

Comment: The set of matrices of determinant zero is not open. The space of traceless matrices is a vector space, hence connected.

Comment: Notice that this space is arc connected: take $A,B$ two matrices in this space then $tA+(1-t)B$ is also in this space! Hence it's connected.

Comment: @MikeMiller Yes true. Thank You. Can u plz explain, I know that GL(n,R) is not connected for n greater than equal to 2. Is it true for n=1?

Comment: @MikeMiller GL(n,R) is not connected because it has two components, one has positive determinant and other has  negative determinant for n greater than equat to 2. What if n=1 ?

Comment: If $n = 1$ then $GL_n\mathbb R = \pm1$, so it has two components here as well.

Comment: @Thurmond Thank you.....